# jQuery Change event for input and select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alert something whenever a drop-down box changes and whenever something is typed into an input. I don't think I can use change for input fields? What would you use for input fields? Also, what about input fields of type file? Same thing. Here is what I have so far and it's not working:

```js
$('input#wrapper, select#wrapper').change(function(){   
    alert('You changed.');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a keypress event to the text box.

```
$("#wrappertext").bind("keypress", function(){
   // your code
});
```

In your sample you have used the same id for the text box and the select box. Change this also.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to use multiple selectors where I tried to set the change event on all input elements and all select elements within the wrapper div. I made a mistake there.

Comment: You can use `input:text` and `select` and then pass `#wrapper` as the context.

Comment: Yeh, I am using `#wrapper select` now for the change event. What event would I use if user has browsed to a file location and selected it?

Answer (score 0):

> when ever something is typed into an
>   input

`change()` happens in input type text happens when the value is change on blur...

try [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or [keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) instead.